# sending canvas content to server in PNG or JPEG format

Tags: html, jsp

I have this code which on executing embed flash in page and on clicking it captures flash bitmap into canvas..here upto works fine but problem is how to send that capture data into canvas to server into PNG or JPEG image format.
I used Jquery webcam plugin and jquery.js to load flash

```
<html>
<body>
<br><br>
<form name="f" id="f" runat="server"><table><tr><!--<td><div id="eflash">
</div></td>-->
<td>
<div id="webcam">
</div></td><td><canvas style="border:2px solid red"  id="canvas" width="320" height="240">
 </canvas>

</td></tr></table>
<br><p><a href="javascript:webcam.capture();void(0);">CLICK</a>**|**<input type="button" id="sendBtn" value="Send" /></p>
</form>
</body></html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/jquery.js"></script>

<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/jquery.flash.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/jquery.webcam.js"></script>

<!--<script>
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('#eflash').flash({src: 'jscam.swf',     width: 220,     height: 140     }); 
    }
);
</script>-->

<script type="text/javascript">
var pos = 0;
var ctx = null;
var cam = null;
var image = null;
jQuery("#webcam").webcam({
width: 320,
height: 240,
mode: "callback",
swffile: "jscam_canvas_only.swf",

onTick: function(remain) {
if (0 == remain)
{jQuery("#status").text("Sorria!");
}
else { 
jQuery("#status").text(remain + " segundo(s) restante(s)...");
}
},

onSave: function(data)
{ 
var col = data.split(";");
var img = image;
for(var i = 0; i < 320; i++)
{ 
var tmp = parseInt(col[i]);
img.data[pos + 0] = (tmp >> 16) & 0xff;
img.data[pos + 1] = (tmp >> 8) & 0xff;
img.data[pos + 2] = tmp & 0xff;
img.data[pos + 3] = 0xff;
pos+= 4; 
}

if (pos >= 4 * 320 * 240)
{ 
ctx.putImageData(img, 0, 0);
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var save_image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
save_image = save_image.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpeg);base64,/, "");
$('input[name=save_image]').val(save_image);
pos = 0;
} 
},

onCapture: function ()
{
jQuery("#flash").css("display", "block");
jQuery("#flash").fadeOut(100, function () {jQuery("#flash").css("opacity", 1);}); 
jQuery("#canvas").show();
webcam.save();
},

onLoad: function ()
{ var cams = webcam.getCameraList();
for(var i in cams) {jQuery("#cams").append("<li>" + cams[i] + "</li>");} 
jQuery("#canvas").hide();}
});    

function getPageSize()
{ 
var xScroll, yScroll; 
if (window.innerHeight && window.scrollMaxY)
{ 
xScroll = window.innerWidth + window.scrollMaxX; 
yScroll = window.innerHeight + window.scrollMaxY;
} 
else 
if (document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.offsetHeight)
{ // all but Explorer Mac
xScroll = document.body.scrollWidth; 
yScroll = document.body.scrollHeight; 
} 
else { // Explorer Mac...would also work in Explorer 6 Strict, Mozilla and Safari
xScroll = document.body.offsetWidth;
yScroll = document.body.offsetHeight;
}

var windowWidth, windowHeight; 
if (self.innerHeight)
{ // all except Explorer 
if(document.documentElement.clientWidth)
{ 
windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
}
else 
{ 
windowWidth = self.innerWidth;
} 
windowHeight = self.innerHeight;
}
else 
if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight)
{ // Explorer 6 Strict Mode 
windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
} 
else 
if (document.body)
{ // other Explorers 
windowWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
windowHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
}

// for small pages with total height less then height of the viewport
if(yScroll < windowHeight)
{
pageHeight = windowHeight;
}
else
{
pageHeight = yScroll;
}
// for small pages with total width less then width of the viewport
if(xScroll < windowWidth)
{
pageWidth = xScroll;
} 
else
{
pageWidth = windowWidth;
}
return [pageWidth, pageHeight];    }

window.addEventListener("load", function()
{
jQuery("body").append("<div id=\"flash\"></div>");
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
if (canvas.getContext)
{
ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 320, 240);
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
ctx.drawImage(img, 320, 240);
}
image = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 320, 240);

}
var pageSize = getPageSize();
jQuery("#flash").css({ height: pageSize[1] + "px" });
}, false); 
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
var pageSize = getPageSize(); 
jQuery("#flash").css({ height: pageSize[1] + "px" });
}, false);


</script>
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf

Comment: no! it's not . how can we achive it btw !